# Writing masked GeoTIFF in rasterio and visualizing in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, masking, rasterio

I have an interpolated raster, which is a masked array, that shows where the data is valid. I want to save it [as masked TIFF](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/masks.html) with [rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

To test, [here's the JSON file](https://pastebin.com/raw/3nUNZ4rb), and [the code](https://pastebin.com/raw/wZsvPiZf):

```py
import rasterio, rasterio.io, rasterio.transform
import numpy as np
import json

with open('data.json') as f:
    d, m = json.load(f)

zi = np.ma.masked_array(d, m)
res = 100000
minx = 2282862
miny = 5309393
dtype = 'uint8'
tr = rasterio.transform.from_origin(minx - res / 2, miny - res / 2, res, -res)

raster_params = {
    'driver': 'GTiff',
    'width': zi.shape[1],
    'height': zi.shape[0],
    'count': 1,
    'dtype': dtype,
    'compress': 'LZMA',
    'crs': {'init': 'epsg:3857'},
    'transform': tr
}

with rasterio.Env(GDAL_TIFF_INTERNAL_MASK=True):
    with rasterio.open('raster.tif', 'w', **raster_params) as dataset:
        dataset.write(np.array([zi.astype(dtype)]))
        dataset.write_mask(zi.mask)
```

As a result, there's one band and it has zeroes instead of `nan` and no mask.

[image: Output_result]

I tried using two layers and writing this way:

```
...
    'count': 2,
...
        dataset.write(np.array([zi.astype(dtype), zi.mask.astype(dtype)]))
```

It creates a band that I can choose in QGIS. But it just hides the layer completely. When Band 2 has `'1'` for data and `'0'` for no-data, it looks like this:

[image: Output_result]

If I do the other way around (`'1'` for no-data, `'0'` for data), the result is the same.

Am I writing it correctly to GeoTIFF?

How to visualize it properly in QGIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. `dtype = 'uint8'` can't store NaN, use `float32` or convert NaN to 0
2. The mask is reversed, so your masked array is masking all the valid data. Either:

   - reverse the mask and just write the masked array, or
   - don't reverse the mask and use a non-masked array and write the mask separately

Example: float32 and reversing the mask:

```py
import rasterio, rasterio.io, rasterio.transform
import numpy as np
import json

with open('data.json') as f:
    d, m = json.load(f)

m = [~np.array(m)]  # reverse the mask

zi = np.ma.masked_array(d, m)
res = 100000
minx = 2282862
miny = 5309393
dtype = 'float32'
tr = rasterio.transform.from_origin(minx - res / 2, miny - res / 2, res, -res)

raster_params = {
    'driver': 'GTiff',
    'width': zi.shape[1],
    'height': zi.shape[0],
    'count': 1,
    'dtype': dtype,
    'compress': 'LZMA',
    'crs': {'init': 'epsg:3857'},
    'transform': tr
}

with rasterio.Env(GDAL_TIFF_INTERNAL_MASK=True):
    with rasterio.open('raster.tif', 'w', **raster_params) as dataset:
        dataset.write(zi.astype(dtype), 1)  # just write correctly masked array
```

[image]